# What does (int -> int) -> (int -> int) mean?

Tags: function, types, syntax, ocaml

I'm doing a school assignment in OCaml and I had a question regarding the meaning of an expression.

When defining function if I, for example, wrote:

```
let iter : int * (int -> int) -> (int -> int)
= fun (n,f) ->
```

What does `(int -> int)` mean? I understand the function itself receives a pair as an argument, but I don't fully understand what the parentheses mean...

Comment: `(int -> int)` is the type of functions from `int` to `int`.

Comment: @gallais that didn't really help much.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parentheses are there to disambiguate between a function of type `(int -> int)` - meaning it takes in a parameter of type `int` and returns an `int` - and possibly just two regular `int`s taken as parameters of that function. Without the first pair of parentheses for example, your `iter` would expect an`(int, int)` tuple, and in case no other parameter is present, expect an `int -> int -> int` as return type.

Note that the second pair of parentheses is not strictly necessary, but it can be a good indicator that you are expecting a function in return. Without that pair of parentheses, the function can be read as expect a tuple of `(int, int -> int)` plus another `int`, returning an `int` for example.

An example of a function with the same signature as your `iter` could be:

```
let random_func: int * (int -> int) -> (int -> int) =
     fun (n, f) -> f
```

Answer (score 1):

Find TL;DR below.

In lambda calculus (please bear with me), which is what ML-languages are rooted from, the core idea is all about abstracting an application or mapping of function to an argument. **Only one argument**.

```
λx[x + 1]
```

The `λ` in the above reads *abstracting function `x + 1` into an application waiting for a value for `x`, guard it from changing, and apply (replace the `x` in the function with the value and calculate)*.

The above in Ocaml would be equivalent to:

```
fun x -> x + 1
```

which has the type `int -> int`, or input type `int` and output type `int`. Now, lambda only deals with one argument at a time. How does that work with functions with multiple arguments like `x*x -2*x + c` (a polynomial function `x2 − 2·x + c`)? It evaluates the argument one at a time just like before.

```
λc[λx[x*x - 2*x + c]]
```

Thus, the output of the previous application becomes the input of the next one, and so on. The Ocaml equivalent would be

```
fun c x -> (x * x) - (2 * x) + c
```

The function has type `int -> int -> int` or `(int -> int) -> int` (chain of input -> output) If you apply the function partially to an argument `x = 3`, you get a reduced function like so:

```
fun c 3 -> (3 * 3) - (2 * 3) + c 
fun c -> 9 - 6 + c
fun c -> 3 + c
```

at which the resulting function would have the type of `int -> int`. This is the basis of currying. It might look confusing at first, but it proves to be very useful and under-appreciated in imperative languages. For instance, you could do something like this:

```
let waiting_for_c_and_x = fun c x -> 2*x + c
let waiting_for_c = waiting_for_c_and_x 10 in
  let result = waiting_for_c 2  (* result = 22 *)
```

**TL;DR**

However, using parentheses to group these chains of inputs/outputs are tricky but necessary in Ocaml because in reality the compiler cannot guess from e.g. `int * int -> int` if you mean an application that accepts an `int * int` pair as an input and return an `int` as an output (which we could parenthesize as `(int * int) -> int`) or one that accepts a pair of `int` and a function of type `int -> int` as argument (which could be written as `int * (int -> int)`).

Applied from [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (very good read)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/#Int)

Comment: Your explanation could be good if you explained that in this particular case, with no parentheses, the function will expect a pair on integers and return a function of type `int -> int -> int` because `*` has a higher priority on `->`.